# Differential input circuit design frequency issue?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, signal-processing, differential

The current design for this differential op amp scales down -/+ 10V 100kHz signal inputs to 0-3.3V for an ADC to properly read. Using a gain of .165, it adjusts -10 to 0 by adding a 1.65V offset, as well as adjusting +10V to 3.3 by the same offset.

The circuit works properly with sine waves, yet overshoots and has major delays with square waves at 100kHz as you can see below.

[image]

This is the current design and the op amp is a OPA340. I have already looked into adding low pass filters, and faster slew rate op amps, yet nothing is successful at higher frequencies.

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use a passive resistor network:

[image]

Insert a high speed buffer amp to the input if you cannot accept the loading or offset voltage leakage to the input. The buffer cannot be an opamp if you aim it to work perfectly in higher frequency than few kHz.