# Using a PGA to scale input voltage ranges?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, gain, programmable-gain-amplifier

I have a current design of a circuit which works well, but I am needing to make a few extensions to it. I am working on a 4 channel oscilloscope. Each channel must be able to take various ranges of input and properly scale it to 0 - 3.3 V for a ADC to process with the best accuracy.

AC signals will be between 0 - 100 kHz with the setup for the following input ranges:

+/- 10V range
+/- 5V Range
+/- 1V Range
+/- 0.5V Range

I already have a working differential op amp circuit design for +/-10V (ATTACHED BELOW) but I need to be able to scale the remaining ranges as well using a programmable gain amplifier instead of multiple resistors and mux combinations on my differential amplifier.

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you used Google to search for "oscilloscope front end" and then pressed the Images tab? Plenty of schematics show up.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480923/differential-input-circuit-design-frequency-issue is this resolved now?